# Grep - Getting the character position in the line of each occurrence

Tags: bash, grep, cygwin, gnu

According to the manual, the option -b can give the byte offset of a given occurence, but it seems to start from the beginning of the parsed content.

I need to retrieve the position of each matching content returned by grep. I used this line, but it's quite ugly:

```
grep '<REGEXP>' | while read -r line ; do echo $line | grep -bo '<REGEXP>' ; done
```

How to get it done in a more elegant way, with a more efficient use of GNU utils?

Example:

```
$ echo "abcdefg abcdefg" > test.txt
$ grep 'efg' | while read -r line ; do echo $line | grep -bo 'efg' ; done < test.txt
4:efg
12:efg
```

(Indeed, this command line doesn't output the line number, but it's not difficult to add it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl is not a GNU util, but can solve your problem nicely:

```
perl -nle 'print "$.:$-[0]" while /efg/g'
```

Comment: Updated (single quotes don't nest). Please show the input that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

With any awk (GNU or otherwise) in any shell on any UNIX box:

```
$ awk -v re='efg' -v OFS=':' '{
    end = 0
    while( match(substr($0,end+1),re) ) {
        print NR, end+=RSTART, substr($0,end,RLENGTH)
        end+=RLENGTH-1
    }
}' test.txt
1:5:efg
1:13:efg
```

All strings, fields, array indices in awk start at 1, not zero, hence the output not looking like yours since to awk your input string is:

```
123456789012345
abcdefg abcdefg
```

rather than:

```
012345678901234
abcdefg abcdefg
```

Feel free to change the code above to `end+=RSTART-1` and `end+=RLENGTH` if you prefer 0-indexed strings.